# Overriding permission required by AbpAuthorize attribute

Tags: asp.net, permissions, authorization, aspnetboilerplate, .net-attributes

I get the concept of Permissions, Roles and Authorization. But I can't get a grip of how the Authorization works when added in multiple places. Let me explain.

I have an application service class with the attribute:
`[AbpAuthorize(PermissionNames.A)]`
Within that class I have a method with the following attribute:
`[AbpAuthorize(PermissionNames.B)]`

In my world the B-permission should override the A-permission, but does it? To me it does not feel like it. Is there a way for me to accomplish the same functionality? To make it even more complex, the A-permission is a `MultiTenancySides.Host` permission, and B is not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In my world the B-permission should override the A-permission, but does it?

No, separate `AbpAuthorize` attributes are `AND` condition.

> Is there a way for me to accomplish the [override] functionality?

That's fundamentally different. You'll have to rewrite `IAuthorizationHelper`.

```cs
public class OverridingAuthorizationHelper : AuthorizationHelper
{
    public OverridingAuthorizationHelper(IFeatureChecker featureChecker, IAuthorizationConfiguration authConfiguration)
        : base(featureChecker, authConfiguration)
    {
    }

    public override Task AuthorizeAsync(IEnumerable<IAbpAuthorizeAttribute> authorizeAttributes)
    {
        if (authorizeAttributes.Any())
        {
            authorizeAttributes = new List<IAbpAuthorizeAttribute> { authorizeAttributes.First() };
        }

        return base.AuthorizeAsync(authorizeAttributes);
    }
}
```

And then replace it in the `PreInitialize` method of your `*.Core` module.

```cs
// using Abp.Configuration.Startup;

public override void PreInitialize()
{
    Configuration.ReplaceService<IAuthorizationHelper, OverridingAuthorizationHelper>();
}
```